# install php intl extension on mountain lion

Tags: php, macos, intl

I'm trying to install rubedo cms, and get an error in the php application:

```
Zend\I18n\Validator component requires the intl PHP extension
```

These are the steps I've taken to install the extension

```
sudo port install php5-intl
sudo cp /opt/local/lib/php54/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/intl.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
sudo pico /private/etc/php.ini
```

add

```
extension=intl.so
```

then

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem.

I needed the right version of intl. I'm running php 5.3, which I think is the reason that when I ran:

```
sudo port install php53-intl
```

it worked.

Significantly, the parent folder also was named the same in the src and destination in the copy.

So my final process was:

```
sudo port install php53-intl
sudo cp /opt/local/lib/php54/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/intl.so  /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
sudo pico /private/etc/php.ini
```

add

```
extension=intl.so
```

then

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: There is an error in your final process. It should be: sudo cp /opt/local/lib/php53/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626 /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/

Comment: If you have MAMP PRO these instructions work well too (obviously changing the appropriate path)

Answer (score 5):

Use [Brew](http://brew.sh/).

e.g. `brew install php56-intl`

That's it! :-)

Comment: Worked. Obviously if people are running php 5.5 etc they will need to use brew install php55-intl Thanks for the snippet .

Comment: How can't i give this a try :) Thanks @fmstoun