# Intl extension is missing ( downloading FOSUSER Bundle)

Tags: php, macos, symfony, fosuserbundle, intl

I m trying to download the FOSUSERBundle ,
when I execute this cmd :

```
php composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle '~2.0@dev'
```

it gaves me this error :

```
 - symfony/icu v1.2.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - symfony/icu v1.2.2 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - Installation request for symfony/icu == 1.2.2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.2].
```

Trying to solve this problem :

1 - I edited /etc/php.ini by uncommenting this line : `extension=php_intl.dll`
2- I downloaded the last stable version of php  `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6` 
the problem still here ,and when I execute php -i the first line is :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_intl.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_intl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
phpinfo()
```

Is there any thing that I can do to solve this problem ? or to downoald FOSUSERBundle Syfony without this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good guide in the [Intl Component docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html#installation) about why you get this error and how to solve it.

You need to install `php_intl` on your system. Check out [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888403/install-php-intl-extension-on-mountain-lion) for Mac OSX. Make sure you install the correct version of the `symfony/icu` afterwards:

- 1.0.*: when the intl extension is not available
- 1.1.*: when intl is compiled with ICU 3.8 or higher
- 1.2.*: when intl is compiled with ICU 4.4 or higher

This has been a problem for many symfony2 users over the past years. Basically there is a Symfony2 implementation of the `php_intl` extension that will replace the module in near future. Check out [this blog post for further details](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-farewell-to-icu-component). Because the change is very significant it will be also merged into the **2.3** and **2.5** branches of Symfony2 as well as the **master / 2.6** version. It has not been tagged yet but should come available soon.

**Edit:** as of October 24, 2014 the new versions are tagged and this issue should be gone forever!